# analyze the highest data in line graph

Tags: r

```
 df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
  timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df1 <- aggregate(death ~ countryName, subset(df), sum)
```

I created the data set with the number of deaths.

Plotting the number of deaths of the 5 countries with the most deaths as a line graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 <- aggregate(death ~ countryName, subset(df), sum)
```

Select top 10 countries from df1

```
top_10_coutries <- df1[order(df1$death,decreasing = T),][1:10,]$countryName
```

Select subset of df with country name in top_10_countries

```
to_plot = df[df$countryName %in% top_10_coutries,]
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(data=to_plot, aes(x=day, y=death, group=countryName)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=countryName))+
  geom_point(aes(color=countryName))+ theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                                          axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Theme is to remove the date labels on the x axis, since it was too crowded